# How to Repost Question?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting, site-crossover

I have a situation where I posted a question on Super User and then realized it would be more likely to get an answer on Ask Ubuntu. So what should I do in this situation? As of right now I have it reposted on AU and the SU question still open? What should I do/have done?

Comment: This might be more appropriate at MSE instead, since it doesn't actually involve SO.

Comment: flag it for a mod to close or migrate.

Comment: If it's on topic on AU is on topic on SU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either:

- **delete** the existing question and ask a new question, or
- **flag** the existing question for migration

Cross-posting questions is not allowed:

> > Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?
>
> NO
>
> Ask the question on the site you think is most applicable. If, like 
>   in this case, it does not get any answer, ask a moderator to 
>   migrate the question, or alternatively, delete it and re-ask it.
>
> <sub>[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64073#64073)</sub>